# For loop containing Scala Futures modifying a List

Tags: scala, concurrency, future

Let's say I have a `ListBuffer[Int]` and I iterate it with a `foreach` loop, and each loop will modify this list from inside a `Future` (removing the current element), and will do something special when the list is empty. Example code:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

val l = ListBuffer(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
l.foreach(n => Future {
  println(s"Processing $n")
  Future {
    l -= n
    println(s"Removed $n")
    if (l.isEmpty) println("List is empty!")
  }
})
```

This is probably going to end very badly. I have a more complex code with similar structure and same needs, but I do not know how to structure it so I can achieve same functionality in a more reliable way.

Comment: Do you need it to be mutable? Why Future inside Future?

Comment: @mfirry I need a way to do something different when the list is empty (that means, when all the elements have been consumed and actions done). So for example, checking that the last item is being processed wouldn't work, as there might be other elements still being processed. The "Future inside Future" part is to mimic the structure of the real code - it has a reason to be like that, I'm simplifying here a bit.

Comment: Ok. But do you really need to modify the buffer?

Comment: mutating a list while iterating it in another thread is strictly not recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you present your problem is really not in the functional paradigm that scala is intended for.

What you seem to want, is to do a list of asynchronous computations, do something at the end of each one, and something else when every one is finished. This is pretty simple if you use continuations, which are simple to implement with `map` and `flatMap` methods on `Future`.

```
val fa: Future[Int] = Future { 1 } 
// will apply the function to the result when it becomes available
val fb: Future[Int] = fa.map(a => a + 1) 
// will start the asynchronous computation using the result when it will become available
val fc: Future[Int] = fa.flatMap(a => Future { a + 2 })
```

Once you have all this, you can easily do something when each of your `Future` completes (successfully):

```
val myFutures: List[Future[Int]] = ???
myFutures.map(futInt => futInt.map(int => int + 2))
```

Here, I will add 2 to each value I get from the different asynchronous computations in the `List`.

You can also choose to wait for all the `Future`s in your list to complete by using `Future.sequence`:

```
val myFutureList: Future[List[Int]] = Future.sequence(myFutures)
```

Once again, you get a `Future`, which will be resolved when each of the `Future`s  inside the input list are successfully resolved, or will fail whenever one of your `Future`s fails. You'll then be able to use `map` or `flatMap` on this new `Future`, to use all the computed values at once.

So here's how I would write the code you proposed:

```
val l = 1 to 10

val processings: Seq[Future[Unit]] = l.map {n =>
  Future(println(s"processing $n")).map {_ => 
    println(s"finished processing $n")
  }
}

val processingOver: Future[Unit] =
  Future.sequence(processings).map { (lu: Seq[Unit]) => 
    println(s"Finished processing ${lu.size} elements")
  }
```

Of course, I would recommend having real functions rather than procedures (returning `Unit`), so that you can have values to do something with. I used `println` to have a code which will produce the same output as yours (except for the prints, which have a slightly different meaning, since we are not mutating anything anymore).